# Validity of Conservation of Momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

Why is Conservation of Momentum only valid when there is no force. Can it be still valid, if force is constant number (not zero).  Please explain.

Comment: You don't even need a calculation to show this doesn't conserve momentum unless that force is zero, as the object will accelerate and so it's momentum will be different at any two points in time.

Answer (score 0):

While proving the conservation of momentum, we assume that there is ***zero net force on the system***, some parts of system may apply force on each other, but their net result for the system is zero, as they cancel out due to Newton's Third law. Hence, there is NO FORCE acting on our system, now using the relation that force is rate of change of momentum, it is easy to see that rate of change of momentum is zero, and a simple integral with respect to time gives momentum to be a constant value. If instead, there IS net force on a system, then rate of change of momentum is constant (non-zero) and momentum is not constant but a linear function of time instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be still valid, if force is constant number (not zero)

Sure, just subtract from each body momentum change due to force applied :

$$ \sum_i \left(p_i - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} F_i dt  \right) = \text{const} $$